# Constraining the parameter space of a function

Tags: functions

Consider the function

$$f(x) = - ax^{2} + bx^{4} + \cos(x/c),$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are arbitrary parameters.

For some region(s) of the parameter space, there are oscillations in the function. My goal is to identify these regions of the parameter space.

Here are three examples:

[image: a busy cat]
[image: a busy dog]
[image: a busy not]
[image: a busy ton]

Does this mean that there are bumps in the function only for $c \sim a$ (and any arbitrary value of $b$)?

Answer (score 0):

There are always oscillations in this function with period $2\pi c$, the plotting range will not allow you to see them if it is smaller than this number, use for instance

```
c = 10
Plot[-0.01 x^2 + 0.01 x^4 + Cos[x/c], {x, -4*Pi*c, 4*Pi*c}, 
PlotRange -> {{-4*Pi*c, 4*Pi*c}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

Comment: I used     Plot[-0.01 x^{2} + 0.01 x^{4} + Cos[x/10000], {x, -4*Pi *(10000), 
  4 *Pi *(10000)}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]

Comment: @nightmarish Try specifying both ranges please

Comment: I tried the following: Plot[x, -0.01 x^{2} + 0.01 x^{4} + Cos[x/10000], 
 PlotRange -> {{x, -4*Pi*(10000), 4*Pi*(10000)}, {-1, 1}}]. It doesn't work either.

Comment: @nightmarish I updated the answer, try with that